# Pandas dataFrame.nunique() : ("unhashable type : 'list'", 'occured at index columns')

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply the .nunique() function to a full dataFrame.

On the following screenshot, we can see that it contains 130 features. [Screenshot of shape and columns of the dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TqtM.png)
The goal is to get the number of different values per feature.
I use the following code (that worked on another dataFrame).

```
def nbDifferentValues(data):
    total = data.nunique()
    total = total.sort_values(ascending=False)
    percent = (total/data.shape[0]*100)
    return pd.concat([total, percent], axis=1, keys=['Total','Pourcentage'])

diffValues = nbDifferentValues(dataFrame)
```

And the code fails at the first line and I get the following error which I don't know how to solve *("unhashable type : 'list'", 'occured at index columns')*: 
[Trace of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYhqV.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You probably have a column whose content are lists.**

**Since lists in Python are mutable they are unhashable.**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, [1,2]),
    (1, [2,3])    
])

#  raises "unhashable type : 'list'" error
df.nunique()
```

**SOLUTION: Don't use mutable structures (like lists) in your dataframe**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, (1,2)),
    (1, (2,3))    
])

df.nunique()

#  0    2
#  1    2
#  dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `nunique` or `unique` in a `pandas.Series` , my preferred approaches are

### Quick Approach

NOTE: It wouldn't hurt if the col values are lists and string type. Also, nested lists might needed to be flattened.

```py
_unique_items = df.COL_LIST.explode().unique()
```

or

```py
_unique_count = df.COL_LIST.explode().nunique()
```

### Alternate Approach

Alternatively, if I wish not to explode the items,

```py
# If col values are strings
_unique_items = df.COL_STR_LIST.apply("|".join).unique()

# Lambda will save if col values are non-strings
_unique_items = df.COL_LIST.apply(lambda _l: "|".join([str(_y) for _y in _i])).unique()
```

### Bonus

`df.COL.apply(json.dumps)` might handle all the cases.

## OP's solution

```py
df['uniqueness'] = df.apply(lambda _x: json.dumps(_x.to_list()), axis=1)
...
# Plug more code
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this problem with `.nunique()` when converting results from a Rest API from dict (or list) to pandas dataframe.  The problem is that one of the columns is stored as a list or dict (common situation in nested json results).  Here is a sample code to remove the columns causing the error.

```py
# this is the dataframe that is causing your issues
df = data.copy()

print(f"Rows and columns: {df.shape}  \n")
print(f"Null values per column: \n{df.isna().sum()}  \n")

# check which columns error when counting number of uniques
ls_cols_nunique = []
ls_cols_error_nunique = []
for each_col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[each_col].nunique()
        ls_cols_nunique.append(each_col)
    except:
        ls_cols_error_nunique.append(each_col)

print(f"Unique values per column: \n{df[ls_cols_nunique].nunique()}  \n")
print(f"Columns error nunique: \n{ls_cols_error_nunique}  \n")
```

This code should split your dataframe columns into 2 lists:

1. Column that can calculate `.nunique()`
2. Column that errors when running `.nunique()`

Then just calculate the `.nunique()` on the columns without errors.

As far as converting the columns with errors, there are other resources that address that with `.apply(pd.series)`.